# É possível declarar Incógnitas no Python para calcular constantes de uma função Matemática?

Tags: python, matemática

Preciso montar uma função quadrática **Y = aX² + bX + c** a partir de valores de **X** e **Y** conhecidos.
Neste caso, estou tratando de **H(Q) = aQ² + bQ + c** (Altura manométrica em função da vazão).

Onde:
H1 = 3; Q1 = 3.4
H2 = 8; Q2 = 2.6
H3 = 15; Q3 = 0.8

... ou ainda ...

H(3.4)=3
H(2.6)=8
H(0.8)=15

Matematicamente, preciso fazer as deduções das constantes "a", "b", "c", onde:
**c = H1 - a*((Q1)^2) - b*(Q1)**
**b = (H2 - a*((Q2)^2) - c) / (Q2)**
**a = (H3 - b*(Q3) - c) / ((Q3)^2)**

Sabendo que ao final eu teria o valor de "a", substituindo nas equações de "b" e "c" consequentemente, como poderia automatizar isso num codigo no Python?

Aprendi em programação que ao declarar uma variável sem valor ela retorna valor igual a 1 (Não sei nem se no Python é assim).

Portanto, como declarar "a", "b", "c" de forma que o programa faça as iterações até achar os valores reais dessas constantes?

Comment: Meu comentário anterior era em grande parte bobagem, por isso o removi. Confundi as coisas. O que você precisa é resolver um sistema linear de equações.

Comment: @LuizVieira A resposta do Jefferson vale, com certeza, receber a recompensa. Eu mesmo queria ter dado e acabei esquecendo. Ficarei feliz se entregar a ele - ou a qualquer outra resposta que possa ainda aparecer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O que você procura é algo que resolva sistema linear.

> Essa resposta será escrita de forma genérica, pode-se aplicá-la em qualquer função cuja forma grossa seja conhecida. No caso, os exemplos serão polinômios de grau 2, conforme sua dúvida, ou de grau 1 para facilitar a explicação de algo não crítico mas necessário.
>
> A resposta é independente de linguagem. Possivelmente farei inicialmente uma abordagem algorítmica pura, mas em versões futuras o código será eventualmente pythonizado

Vamos dividir a resposta em duas partes? A primeira é: montando o sistema linear. Na prática ela não responde nada, mas deixa tudo pronto e normalizado para a segunda parte (sem falar que é basicamente independente): resolvendo um sistema linear.

A segunda parte vou criar uma subdivisão: e quando não há resposta?

Pronto? Aperte os cintos, vamos lá.

## Montando o sistema linear

Que tal definir o que é um "sistema linear" antes?

Primeiramente, o nome completo é "sistema de equações linear". Então, termo a termo:

- *equação*: algo dado como uma ruma operação aritmética entre variáveis e constantes que chega em um valor exato.
- *equação linear*: uma equação apenas com operações lineares. Uma operação linear é aquela entre duas constantes ou entre uma variável em seu valor base  e uma constante.

  > *15 x A* é linear, já *A^2* é quadrático, e *sqrt(A)* pertence ao grau 0.5, sendo também não linear
- sistema de equações: quando se tem uma única equação, temos um sistema de uma equação; quando temos 2 equações que compartilham variáveis, temos um sistema de 2 equações; o mesmo vale para 3, 4 ou `n` equações

Quando sabemos a forma da equação e desejamos encontrar seus parâmetros, e também temos fornecidos alguns pares de "entrada/resultado", então podemos substituir o `X` em seus valores e igualar ao `Y` fornecido.

Por exemplo, suponhamos que temos uma reta desconhecida. Só isso me fornece sua estrutura: `Y = a*X+ b`. Se soubermos que ela passa pelos pontos `(0, 0)` e `(2, 2)`, então temos o seguinte sistema de equações:

```
a*X + b = Y  (forma geral)
a*0 + b = 0 (ponto (0,0))
a*2 + b = 2 (ponto (2,2))
```

Poderíamos ter uma parábola (portanto, fórmula `Y = a*X**2 + b*X + c`) com os seguintes pontos conhecidos:

```
(0, 10)
(2, 14)
(10, 110)
```

Que eu poderia montar o sistema da seguinte forma:

```
a*X**2 + b*X +c = Y (forma geral)
a*0**2 + b*0 + c = 10 (ponto (0,0))
a*2**2 + b*2 + c = 14 (ponto (2,14))
a*10**2 + b*10 + c = 110 (ponto (10,110))
```

Formalmente, como posso representar meu sistema linear? Bem, através de uma única matriz que contém em si a seguinte fórmula:

```
A x b = c
```

Onde:

- `A` é a matriz de parâmetros
- `b` é o vetor (coluna) de incógnitas; e
- `c` é o vetor (coluna) com os resultados

A representação é uma matriz única com as informações de `A` é uma coluna extra para `c`. O valor de `b` já está codificado implicitamente. Os dois sistemas lineares descritos acima seriam representados assim:

> considere a barra vertical apenas um recurso estilístico para separar o conteúdo de `A` do vetor `c`

```
0 1 | 0
2 1 | 2
```

```
  0  0  1 |  10
  4  2  1 |  14
100 10  1 | 110
```

## Resolvendo um sistema linear

Meu método favorito de resolução de sistemas lineares é através de eliminação gaussiana. Como ela se dá? Através de 2 ou 3 passos que se repetem até o fim:

1. normalização para o primeiro termo não nulo valer 1
2. anular esse termo nas colunas abaixo
3. possivelmente, reordenar as linhas para que se possa fazer novamente os passos 1 e 2

Você só pode executar 3 tipos de operações com matrizes:

1. multiplicar uma linha por um número
2. combinar linhas
3. mudar linhas de posição

Peguemos o primeiro sistema linear:

```
0 1 0
2 1 2
```

A primeira coisa aqui é reordená-lo, pois a primeira linha não permite a normalização necessária. Ficaria assim após reordenar:

```
2 1 2
0 1 0
```

Depois, normalizemos pelo primeiro termo não nulo. Nesse caso, implica multiplicar a primeira linha por 1/2; a segunda linha não exige mudança:

```
1 0.5 1
0   1 0
```

Pronto, já chegamos no final da matriz. Não há operações mais. Agora que já alcançamos o valor de uma variável, então vamos calcular o valor das outras variáveis. Essa ultima linha pode ser lida dessa maneira, por isso que alcançamos o valor da variável:

```
1*b = 0
```

Depois desse primeiro passo da eliminação gaussiana, vamos sair de algo que estava assim:

```
a00 a01 a02 a03 c0
a10 a11 a12 a13 c1
a20 a21 a22 a23 c2
a30 a31 a32 a33 c3
```

Obtemos algo assim:

```
1 a'01 a'02 a'03 c'0
0    1 a'12 a'13 c'1
0    0    1 a'23 c'2
0    0    0    1 c'3
```

Então, daí, se fizer a operação da eliminação gaussiana indo para cima teremos uma matriz diagonal. Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
1 0 0 0 c*0
0 1 0 0 c*1
0 0 1 0 c*2
0 0 0 1 c'3
```

Isso significa que obtemos o resultado desejado para o sistema linear. Então, voltando para o sistema linear anterior:

```
1 0.5 1
0   1 0
```

Podemos remover o `0.5` da primeira linha somando-a com `0.5 * l2`. Isso daria:

```
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

Portanto, podemos concluir que `(a, b) = (1, 0)`, que é a mesma coisa de dizer que a fórmula é `y = 1*x + 0`, ou então `y = x`

Para o outro caso, da parábola, vamos resolver?

```
  0  0  1  10
  4  2  1  14
100 10  1 110
```

Vamos primeiro mudar a posição das linhas 1 e 3, para poder dar seguimento à eliminação gaussiana:

```
100 10  1 110
  4  2  1  14
  0  0  1  10
```

Normalizando a primeira linha:

```
1 0.1 0.01 1.10
4   2    1   14
0   0    1   10
```

Fazendo `l2 = l2 - 4*l1`:

```
1 0.1 0.01 1.10
0 1.6 0.96 9.60
0   0    1   10
```

Normalizando `l2`:

```
1 0.1 0.01 1.10
0   1  0.6    6
0   0    1   10
```

Agora, indo de baixo para cima. Fazendo `l2 = l2 - 0.6*l3`:

```
1 0.1 0.01 1.10
0   1    0    0
0   0    1   10
```

Agora, indo de baixo para cima. Fazendo `l1 = l1 - 0.0.1*l3`:

```
1 0.1 0  1
0   1 0  0
0   0 1 10
```

Fazendo `l1 = l1 - 0.1*l2`:

```
1 0 0  1
0 1 0  0
0 0 1 10
```

Portanto, concluímos que `(a, b, c) = (1, 0, 10)`. A fórmula é `y = x**2 + 10`.

### Para o seu caso

O sistema linear da sua questão é:

```
11.56 3.4 1  3 # H(3.4) = 3
 6.76 2.6 1  8 # H(2.6) = 8
 0.64 0.8 1 15 # H(0.8) = 15
```

Só resolver o sistema linear agora, simples assim. Seja feliz =D

### E quando não há resposta?

Há casos em que é impossível achar uma resposta de um sistema linear. As duas possibilidades são:

1. há uma liberdade de grau `> 0`; você só obtém resposta quando a liberdade é de grau `= 0`
2. há uma incoerência nos dados, mas para isso é necessário fornecer mais equações do que variáveis

Há duas possibilidades para cair no caso em que há graus de liberdade:

1. menos equações do que variáveis
2. uma equação é uma combinação linear das outras equações

O segundo caso (para polinômios do segundo grau) não ocorre ao se fornecer pares de entrada/saída. Mas hipoteticamente pode ocorrer com grau 3+.

Com um polinômio do grau 3, temos quatro parâmetros:

1. `a`, relacionado a `X**3`
2. `b`, relacionado a `X**2`
3. `c`, relacionado a `X`
4. `d`, independente de `X`

Peguemos `l1`, `l2` e `l3` da seguinte forme:

```
a00 a01 a02 1 c1 #l1
a10 a11 a12 1 c2 #l2
a20 a21 a22 1 c3 #l3
```

Então, façamos `l4 = l3 - l2 + l1`:

```
a30 = a20 - a10 + a00
a31 = a21 - a11 + a01
a32 = a32 - a22 + a02
a33 = 1 - 1 + 1 = 1
c3 = c2 - c1 + c0
```

Com isso, temos:

```
a00           a01           a02           1 c0         #l1
a10           a11           a12           1 c1         #l2
a20           a21           a22           1 c2         #l3
(a20-a10+a00) (a21-a11+a01) (a32-a22+a02) 1 (c2-c1+c0) #l4
```

Toda tentativa de fazer operação de diagonalização acarretará em ter uma linha nula. Se não for alterada a ordem das linhas, `l4` certamente será nula.

O que isso significa? Que os valor de `(a,b,c)` são dependentes linearmente de `d`. Existe um grau de liberdade, e ele é a variável `d`.

Comment: Jefferson muito obrigado. Estou admirado com o nível da sua resposta.  Vou ficar com a resposta do Anderson abaixo pois ele me dá diretamente a classe ou biblioteca da função matemática no Python. Mas tua explicação ta tá show de bola, só vou ter que estuda-la mais a fundo para entender melhor depois.

Comment: @h1k3r, a solução do Anderson realmente está mais idiomática. Eu tenho uma deficiência de não conhecer a fundo as bibliotecas padrão das linguagens, mas normalmente trato consigo tratar os problemas com algoritmos próprios =) E, sim, muitas vezes uma solução _homebrew_ é pior do que uma advinda de bibliotecas, mas é sempre bom conhecer a base e poder se virar em ambientes limitados, sem falar que fica independente de linguagem

Answer (score 12):

Sim, é possível.

O Python possui uma biblioteca própria para trabalhar com matemática simbólica: [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/pt/index.html). Você pode criar símbolos utilizando a função `symbols`, ou a classe `Symbol`:

```
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
y = x + 1

print(y)  # x + 1
```

E é possível resolver os símbolos substituindo-os por valores numéricos:

```
print(y.subs(x, 41))  # 42
```

Bem como o SymPy já possui funções para resolução de sistemas lineares:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve

a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c')

system = [
    a*3.4**2 + b*3.4 + c - 3,
    a*2.6**2 + b*2.6 + c - 8,
    a*0.8**2 + b*0.8 + c - 15
]

result = linsolve(system, (a, b, c))
```

O sistema definido em `system` é exatamente o descrito na pergunta. Perceba somente que a biblioteca espera equações que são iguais a zero, portanto se você possui algo como `x - a = 5`, você precisa definir como `x - a - 5 = 0`, que são equivalentes.

A função `linsolve` irá resolver o sistema com base nos símbolos `a`, `b` e `c`, devolvendo os valores dos mesmos, se o sistema possuir solução.

Para detalhes da matemática que fundamenta todo este processo, por favor, veja a [resposta do Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/315538/5878) - altamente recomendado ler, mesmo que não vá aplicá-la diretamente.

Comment: A sensação que eu tive com sua resposta foi `import antigravity`