# Como funciona o Cubic-Bezier em Animações com CSS?

Tags: html5, css3, css-animations, ui, keyframes

Quando vamos fazer uma animação com CSS temos vários parâmetros que podemos usar.

Ex:

```
animation-name: none
animation-duration: 0s
animation-timing-function: ease
animation-delay: 0s
animation-iteration-count: 1
animation-direction: normal
animation-fill-mode: none
animation-play-state: running
```

Minha dúvida é com relação ao **`animation-timing-function`** e como se usa o **`cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0)`** para controlar a animação...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é o que corresponde cada um desses **0**: `cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 0)` 
Não entendi muito bem como mudar esses valores em função do que vejo animado na tela. Percebi valores de `animation-timing-function` como `ease`, `ease-in`, `ease-in-ou`, `linear` são valores pré definidos e vc não consegue customiza-los, para isso temos o `cubic-bezier`, mas não entendi como controlar esses valores...

Exemplo de código com uma animação usando `cubic-bezier`, repare que no final da animação tem um "*bounce*" e ela volta pro ponto original antes de começar. Só é possível conseguir esse efeito usando `cubic-bezier` *(já que não tem um valor pré-definido para ele tipo o `ease`)*.

Mas não entendi direito o que realmente acontece quando estou manipulando esses números. Não entendi bem como essa "curva" de tempo/progresso funciona.

```css
.box {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;

 animation: 
                    box 
                    2s 
                    infinite 
                    alternate 
                    cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

@keyframes box {
 to {
  margin-left: 50%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## TL;DR

Os quatro parâmetros definem os dois pontos de controle da Curva de Bézier, P<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) e P<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>), para grau 3.

```
cubic-bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

## A Curva de Bézier

A Curva de Bézier é uma forma de interpolação entre um conjunto de pontos e entende-se por interpolação uma aproximação, ou média, que busca reproduzir o mesmo comportamento apresentado pelos pontos interpolados. Por exemplo, se você possui dois pontos alinhados, consegue traçar um segmento de reta entre eles, estimando que todos os pontos intermediários possuem o mesmo comportamento que os dois pontos que originaram o segmento de reta; essa estimativa é o que chamamos de interpolação. Em uma linguagem mais leiga, seria como afirmar que se saiu do ponto A e chegou no ponto C, provavelmente passou pelo ponto B, dado que B está entre A e C.

Matematicamente, a Curva de Bézier é representada por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde:

- (x, y) é o ponto da curva em um plano bi-dimensional;
- n é a ordem da curva;
- k o índice de controle da somatória;
- t um parâmetro utilizado para percorrer a curva;

Uma Curva de Bézier de ordem n faz a interpolação entre n+1 pontos.

[image: Exemplos de curvas de Bézier para linear, quadrática e cúbica]

<sup>[Fonte](https://thatsmaths.com/2014/02/06/french-curves-and-bezier-splines/): exemplos de curvas de Bézier linear, quadrática e cúbica.</sup>

## A Curva de Bézier Cúbica

A função `cubic-bezier`, como esperado, utiliza o caso particular da Curva de Bézier para n = 3, desta forma possui 4 pontos de controle - pontos que geram interpolados e gerarão a curva. O ponto inicial, P<sub>0</sub>, será sempre a origem, (0, 0), já o ponto final, P<sub>3</sub>, será sempre o ponto (1, 1), restando apenas definir os pontos P<sub>1</sub> e P<sub>2</sub>, que são definidos justamente nos parâmetros da função.

Se você simplificar a equação com os parâmetros já conhecidos, terá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conhecendo os pontos P<sub>0</sub>(0, 0) e P<sub>3</sub>(1, 1), bem como os pontos P<sub>1</sub> e P<sub>2</sub> que são definidos pelos parâmetros, somos capazes de traçar o gráfico interpolando os pontos.

### Como calcular P<sub>1</sub> e P<sub>2</sub> a partir do gráfico que desejo montar?

Os pontos P<sub>0</sub> e P<sub>3</sub> são conhecidos, então precisamos apenas determinar quem é P<sub>1</sub> e P<sub>2</sub> para definirmos os parâmetros da equação.

Uma das formas a se fazer isso é montar um sistema de equações. Lembrando que cada ponto é composto por duas dimensões, teremos o desafio de determinar o valor de quatro variáveis. Sabendo os valores de B(t) por onde deseja que a curva passe, você pode resolver o sistema para essas variáveis.

O [Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado) já fez [uma resposta tratando sobre soluções de sistemas lineares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/315538/5878) que pode ser utilizada como base.

A outra alternativa, que costuma a ser mais viável na grande maioria dos casos é a tentativa e erro. Entendendo que o ponto P<sub>1</sub> influencia o início da animação e o ponto P<sub>2</sub> influencia o final da mesma, você já pode posicioná-los conforme desejar e ir ajustando conforme sua necessidade.

## Ferramentas

Obviamente que você não precisa fazer a tentativa e erro na mão. Já existem ferramentas que te auxiliam na criação de uma Curva de Bézier cúbica.

- http://cubic-bezier.com

Outras mais existem.

## Exemplos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Ease In

A animação `ease-in` é conhecida por iniciar de forma lenta e ser mais rápida no final.

```css
#animations:hover .box {
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.box.ease-in {
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.box.cubic-bezier {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

section > section {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="animations">
  <header>
    <h1>Ease In</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <strong>Animação ease-in do navegador</strong>
    <pre>transition-timing-function: ease-in</pre>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="box ease-in"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <strong>Animação ease-in definida pelo Google Material</strong>
    <pre>transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);</pre>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="box cubic-bezier"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

---

### Ease Out

A animação `ease-out` é conhecida por iniciar de forma rápida e ser mais lenta no final.

```css
#animations:hover .box {
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.box.ease-out {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.box.cubic-bezier {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

section > section {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="animations">
  <header>
    <h1>Ease Out</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <strong>Animação ease-out do navegador</strong>
    <pre>transition-timing-function: ease-out</pre>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="box ease-out"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <strong>Animação ease-out definida pelo Google Material</strong>
    <pre>transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);</pre>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="box cubic-bezier"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```