# calcular as variáveis de um sistema linear n x n

Tags: python

Desenvolver um programa em Python para calcular as variáveis de um sistema linear n x n . As dimensões do sistema devem ser fornecidas pelo usuário, bem como os valores das matrizes A e B.

Até agora só consegui inserir isso

```
import numpy as np

lista1 = []
linha1 = []
nc = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))
nl = int(input('Quantas linhas? '))
for c1 in range(0, nl):
    linha1 = []
    for c2 in range(0, nc):
        n = int(input('Número L[{0}] C[{1}]: '.format(c1 + 1,c2 + 1)))
        linha1.append(n)
    lista1.append(linha1)
print(lista1)

lista2 = []
linha2 = []
nc = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))
nl = int(input('Quantas linhas? '))
for c1 in range(0, nl):
    linha2 = []
    for c2 in range(0, nc):
        n = int(input('Número L[{0}] C[{1}]: '.format(c1 + 1,c2 + 1)))
        linha2.append(n)
    lista2.append(linha2)
print(lista2)
```

Comment: Pode ou não pode usar a `numpy` ?!

Comment: Fortemente vinculada: [É possível declarar Incógnitas no Python para calcular constantes de uma função Matemática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315484/5878)

Comment: se é nxn vc pode retirar uma chamada do input, e fazer apenas 'input('entre x')', vc pode usar random para gerar os numeros vem melhor doque ficar entrando um a um